# How to insert specific text after a file's name in order to rename it, in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pickle, google-coral

I am using the Google Coral board. The script that I am using can be found here: [Coral's classify_image.py](https://github.com/google-coral/tflite/blob/master/python/examples/classification/classify_image.py)

I modified it (everything in **bold**) so that I can store all the inference times. Basically, I am storing them in a list and then use "pickle" to save that list into a file. The name of the file is: "file_inference_time"

The problem is that I have many models and if I start running all of them, that file will be overwritten. So I would like that the name of the model be attached. Ex:

What I have:

`file_inference_time`

what I would like to have:

`file_inference_time_mobilenet_v2`

WHAT I HAVE

```
print('----INFERENCE TIME----')
  print('Note: The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes',
        'loading the model into Edge TPU memory.')

  **list_inference_time = []** #List where the "inference_time" will be stored

  for _ in range(args.count):
    start = time.monotonic()
    interpreter.invoke()
    inference_time = time.monotonic() - start
    classes = classify.get_output(interpreter, args.top_k, args.threshold)

     **list_inference_time.append(inference_time)** #Adding "inference_time" into the list

    print('%.1fms' % (inference_time * 1000))


  print('----SAVING INFERENCE TIME IN A LIST----')
  print('Note: "inference_time" has been saved in "list_inference_time" list')

  **with open ("file_inference_time", "wb")) as fp:   
      pickle.dump(list_inference_time, fp)**
```

MY ATTEMPT TO GET WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO HAVE

```
  with open ('file_inference_time_{}'.format((args.model), "wb")) as fp:   
      pickle.dump(list_inference_time, fp)
```

THE EXECUTION AND ERROR THAT I GET
[image]

---

I also thought of using a dictionary instead of a list.

---

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track, however the error that you are getting is an [ENOENT](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) throws by the filesystem. 
For python, when opening a file with write bytes mode, it should open a new file to write to it. However, in your case, it is trying to write to a new file that is in a directory that doesn't now exist (`file_inference_time_models`).
Here is an illustration:

```
# Writing to a new file
with open('newfile.txt', 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(bytes('test bytes','utf-8')) # WORK FINE

# Also writing to a new file but to a directory that doesn't exist.
with open('new_dir/test.txt', 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(bytes('test bytes','utf-8')) # ENOENT
```

That just a summary of why you are running into that issue while executing the code. The easiest way to fix that would be to create the directory before running the code.
However I don't think this is what you want, what you want is `file_inference_time_mobilenet_v2`, not `file_inference_time_models/model_name.tflite` so my suggestion is check over your logic. When you are taking the whole string from `args.model`, it is giving you a whole models directory + model name, if you would trim that string to get just the part you want, then this would all works.

Cheers!